# C++/CLI Open XML SDK Excel cannot use AddNewPart

Tags: c++-cli, openxml

I am using C++/CLI for a school project and I need to export some data into Excel format (xlsx). The problem is that this code has parts like AddNewPart that are underlined with red by Visual Studio (it says that the specified class has no member AddNewPart) but the code is compiled and the application runs but the result is a corrupted xlsx file (when I tried to open it with excel it says that is corrupt).

```
SpreadsheetDocument ^doc = SpreadsheetDocument::Create(path_get, SpreadsheetDocumentType::Workbook);

WorkbookPart ^wbookpart = doc->AddWorkbookPart();
wbookpart->Workbook = gcnew Workbook();

WorksheetPart^ worksheetPart = wbookpart->AddNewPart<WorksheetPart^>();
SheetData^ sheetData = gcnew SheetData();
worksheetPart->Worksheet = gcnew Worksheet();
worksheetPart->Worksheet->AppendChild(sheetData);

Sheets^ sheets = doc->WorkbookPart->Workbook->AppendChild<Sheets^>(gcnew Sheets());
Sheet^ sheet = gcnew Sheet();
sheet->Id = doc->WorkbookPart->GetIdOfPart(worksheetPart);
sheet->SheetId = 1;
sheet->Name = "mySheet";
sheets->Append(sheet);
wbookpart->Workbook->Save();
doc->Close();
```

Comment: At first glance, it looks like you're missing a couple `^`. However, telling us the exact error message will help greatly.

Comment: I added all the code and the error! Thanks for your quick response!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you, Visual Studio reports that the class has no member, but it still compiles and still seems to populate the parameters for me.  Try stepping through with the debugger and see if this is the same for you. If I try to rename AddNewPart to something that definitely doesn't exist, it doesn't compile for me.

As a less complicated check, GetIdOfPart is also reporting the same error message for me, but that parameter definitely fills in on the debugger despite visual studio claiming the class has no member.